# difference between @Component and @Configuration in Spring 3

Tags: java, spring, spring-3

I came across two annotations provided by Spring 3 ([@Component](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Component.html) and [@Configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html))
I am a bit confused between these.
Here is what I read about `@Component`

> Put this “context:component” in the bean configuration file, it means,
> enable the auto-scanning feature in Spring. The base-package is indicate
> where are your components stored, Spring will scan this folder and
> find out the bean (annotated with @Component) and register it in
> Spring container.

So I am wondering what is the use of `@Configuration` then if `@Controller` will register my beans without the need to declare them in the spring configuration XML file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`@Configuration` is the heart of the Java-based configuration mechanism that was introduced in Spring 3. It provides an alternative to XML-based configuration.

So the 2 following snippets are identical:

```
<beans ...>
    <context:component-scan base-package="my.base.package"/>
    ... other configuration ...
</beans>
```

and:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "my.base.package")
public class RootConfig {
    ... other configuration ...
}
```

In both cases Spring will scan in `my.base.package` and below for classes annotated with `@Component` or one of the other annotations that are meta-annotated with `@Component` such as `@Service`.

Answer (score 18):

From Book Pro Spring Integration

`@Configuration` classes are just like regular `@Components` classes, except that methods annotated with `@Bean` are used to factory beans. Note that a `@Component` with `@Bean` annotated methods works the same way, except that scopes are not respected and the `@Bean` methods are re-invoked (no caching in play), so `@Configuration` is preferred, even though it requires CGLIB

Comment: "Note that A is like B except that B behaves like X. Note that A also behaves like X." Great.

Answer (score 12):

Here is difference with full example :-

```
//@Configuration or @Component
public static class Config {
    @Bean
    public A a() {
        return new A();
    }
    //**please see a() method called inside b() method**
    @Bean
    public B b() {
        return new B(a());
    }
}
```

1) Here if Config class annotated with @configuration , than a() method and b() method , both will be called **once** .

2)Here if Config class annotated with @component , than b() method will be called **once** but a() method  will be called **twice** .

**Problem in (2)** :-  since we have noticed the problem with @component annotation .
This second configuration (2) is totally incorrect because spring will create a singleton bean of A, but B will obtain another instance of A which is out of the spring context control.

**Solution** :- we can use @autowired annotation with @component annotation  inside Config class .

```
@Component
public static class Config {
    @Autowired
    A a;

    @Bean
    public A a() {
        return new A();
    }

    @Bean
    public B b() {
        return new B(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think b will be called once and a twice in (2

Answer (score 3):

Although this is old, but elaborating on JavaBoy And Vijay's answers, with an example:

```
@Configuration
public class JavaConfig {
    @Bean
    public A getA() {
        return new A();
    }
}

@Component
@ComponentScan(basePackages="spring.example")
public class Main() {
    @Bean
    public B getB() {
        return new B();
    }
    @Autowired
    JavaConfig config;

    public static void main(String[]a) {
        Main m = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Main.class)
            .getBean(Main.class);
        /* Different bean returned everytime on calling Main.getB() */
        System.out.println(m.getB());
        System.out.println(m.getB());
        /* Same bean returned everytime on calling JavaConfig.getA() */
        System.out.println(m.config.getA());
        System.out.println(m.config.getA());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`@Component` is a generic stereotype annotation which can indicate any of the candidate components i.e; `@Repository, @Service, @Controller` and these candidates are eligible for auto-detection.

Where as `@Configuration` is used to create component which is used by spring framework to create the application context, internally `@Configuration` makes use of `@Component` it makes sense reason being even that's a spring component which the framework itself creates.