# Difference between Spring annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations

**Questions:**

1) Difference between `@Component` and `@Configuration`?

I have read that both remove the necessity of wiring code to be put in XML, but did not get the difference between these.

2) What are the differences between `@Autowired`, `@Inject` and `@Resource`?
- Which one to use when?
- What are the pros/cons of each?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41802044/2167531

Answer (score 56, accepted):

`@Component` and `@Configuration` are indeed very different types of annotations.

`@Component` and similar annotations (`@Service`, `@Repository`, etc. )and its [JSR-330](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr330/index.html) counterpart `@Named` allow you to declare beans that are to be picked up by autoscanning with  `<context:component-scan/>` or `@ComponentScan` they register the bean definition for the classes, so they are roughly equivalent to declaring the specified beans with the `<bean ... />` tag in XML. This bean types will adhere to the standard proxy creation policies.

`@Configuration` annotation was designed as the replacement of the XML configuration file. To create `@Configuration` annotated beans, Spring will always use `CGLIB` to subclass the `@Configuration` annotated class, overriding its `@Bean` annotated method to replace it with the bean lookup method to make singleton beans to be created only once. (Spring does not use `CGLIB` to intercept *internal* method calls of *normal* Spring beans, it creates a separate instance of proxy instead(same way like JDK proxy does). Doing so allows to use proxies to avoid cardinality mismatch - for example a proxy singleton can fetch current session bean, which is not possible with class inheritance only. ). Despite that, `@Configuration` annotated classes are still able to use annotated(`@Autowired`, `@Inject` etc.) fields and properties to request beans (and even other `@Configuration` annotated beans too) from the container.

**Example** from 4.12.5 section of the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java)

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

  @Bean
  public ClientService clientService1() {
    ClientServiceImpl clientService = new ClientServiceImpl();
    clientService.setClientDao(clientDao());
    return clientService;
  }
  @Bean
  public ClientService clientService2() {
    ClientServiceImpl clientService = new ClientServiceImpl();
    clientService.setClientDao(clientDao());
    return clientService;
  }

  @Bean
  public ClientDao clientDao() {
    return new ClientDaoImpl();
  }
}
```

in the example above only one `ClientDao` instance will be created.

`@Autowired` is Spring annotation, while `@Inject` is a JSR-330 annotation.
`@Inject` is equivalent to `@Autowired` or `@Autowired(required=true)`, but you can't get `@Autowired(required=false)` behavior with the JSR-330 `@Inject`annotation. This annotation always uses by-type autowiring.

Spring implements [JSR-250](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=250) `@Resource` annotation in a rather special way. `@Resource` was originally designed for locating JNDI resources in Java EE, but Spring widens it applicability making it possible to wire to any bean in the container(JNDI resources are available as beans with the help of [SimpleJndiBeanFactory](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jndi/support/SimpleJndiBeanFactory.html)). 
The name of the corresponding bean can be specified as `name` attribute of `@Resource` annotation, if no name was specified, then the name of the annotated field or property will be used. Another strange feature is that if no bean with the property name was found spring will fallback to by-type wiring.

**Example**
Imagine that we have an `AlphaClass` bean named *beanAlpha* and a `BetaClass` bean *beanBeta* in the container.

```
@Resource 
BetaClass something;  // Wires to beanBeta - by-type

@Resource 
BetaClass beanAlpha;  // Will throw exception, because "beanAlpha" is not BetaClass -> it's a bad idea to use @Resource as a replacement of @Autowired

@Resource 
Object beanAlpha;  //Wires to beanAlpha - by-name
```

So it's a good practice to always specify resource name explicitly when using `@Resource` annotation.

**Documentation**

[Spring annotations](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java)

[Bean standard annotations](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-standard-annotations)

**update** fixed JSR references as *shevchik* has pointed out. DI specific annotations are provided by JSR-330, which was developed by Google (Guice Framework) and SpringSource(Spring Framework) engineers. `@Resource` is JNDI based and provided by [JSR-250](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=250).

Comment: "@Named and @Inject" are JSR330 annotations. "@Resource, @PostConstruct, @PreDestroy" are JSR250.

Answer (score 22):

`@Component` is equivalent to `<bean>`,
`@Configuration` is equivalent to `<beans>`.

Comment: If this is true, then why do they seem to work interchangeably?

Comment: Its neat and simple

Comment: `@Component` and `@Configuration` are essentially the same. The main difference that I can see is that any `@Bean` methods on a `@Configuration` class will be memoized (cached on first execution so that all future requests just return the same object without executing the method).

Answer (score 5):

In most the answers above, users suggest to say that @Component and @ Configuration serve different purposes. But I do not see it happening in reality.

But I have a simple Spring MVC application.

```
@Configuration
    public class SpringConfiguration {

@Bean
public  InternalResourceViewResolver initViewResolver(){
    InternalResourceViewResolver x = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    x.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
    x.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return x;
}

}
```

This main class works fine even if it is annotated as @Component instead of @Configuration.

Similarly inside a class annotated as @Component if you have methods annotated with @Bean, those beans are created when context is loaed.

So I think, it is just for code readability that we should mark main configuration class as @Configuration and other classes with @Component. 
Actual execution wise there seems no difference.

Comment: There is at least one difference between Configuration and Component. Configuration allows for your Beans to have inter-bean dependencies, while Component does not. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java-basic-concepts

Comment: Any `@Bean` methods on a `@Configuration` class will be memoized (cached on first execution so that all future requests just return the same object without executing the method). That is not the case for `@Component`s. Their methods will run every time, possibly returning a new object every time (even though that object might be `.equals` equivalent with all of the previous executions' returned values). See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41802044/2167531

Answer (score 2):

On the difference between `@Autowired`, `@Inject` and `@Resource` you can look [here](http://blogs.sourceallies.com/2011/08/spring-injection-with-resource-and-autowired/). Here you can thorough description and comparison.

What concerns the first difference: `@Configuration` is used as replacement for `XML`-based configuration, ie. it marks classes as the ones used for `Java`-based configuration, see [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java). In turn, `@Component` is actually used to mark classes as the ones to be instantiated by `Spring` and `@Configuration` is meta-annotated by `@Component` annotation.

`@Component` and `@Configuration` serve different purposes so it doesn't make sense to compare them.

Comment: In the link mentioned by you also states that Annotating a class with the @Configuration indicates that the class can be used by the Spring IoC container as a source of bean definitions. So I really don't understand how it is different from @Component?

Comment: The real difference according to Spring Java docs is that in @Configuration annotated classes `'inter-bean references' are guaranteed to respect scoping and AOP semantics` (a quotation from [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html)). In @Component annotated classes `scoping semantics are not respected ... for inter-bean method invocations in this mode`. Also this difference is weakly documented according to this [ticket](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-9425).

Answer (score 2):

1) If you want XML configuration, then ignore @Configuration, as this is only useful for Java-based config. XML config is probably best for someone unfamiliar with Spring as there are more examples available.

@Component annotated classes are picked up during component scanning. Use them to label classes that you want to expose as Spring beans. Again, you can just declare all of your beans in the XML config and ignore @Component altogether.

2) If you are happy to tie your application to Spring, then use @Autowire rather than the javax equivalent @Inject. I'd suggest that accepting a dependency to Spring is the best way to start.