# Class compiles and tests pass, but then Spring throws No default constructor found error publishing to app server

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Config:

```
@Configuration
public class CoreConfig {

    @Bean
    public StatusService statusService(StatusPersistenceService statusPersistenceService) {
        return new StatusEventHandler(statusPersistenceService);
    }
}
```

Class Spring is complaining doesn't have a default constructor

```
@Configuration
public class StatusEventHandler implements StatusService {

    private final StatusPersistenceService statusPersistenceService;

    @Autowired
    public StatusEventHandler(final StatusPersistenceService statusPersistenceService) {
        this.statusPersistenceService = statusPersistenceService;
    }

}
```

Controller where this bean is injected:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/showStatus")
public class ShowStatusController {

    @Autowired
    private StatusService statusService;

}
```

This compiles and the test passes, but when publishing to the app server, I get the below error. Why does Spring think there should be a default no-arg constructor?

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'statusEventHandler' 

...

No default constructor found;
```

Comment: Do you have a `@ComponentScan` on your `CoreConfig` class?

Comment: No I don't have `@ComponentScan` on the `CoreConfig` class. Should I? Otherwise Spring won't know about StatusEventHandler for example?

Comment: Nevermind, just see @Boris' answer.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis OP also needs to define persistence service bean  in the core Config i.e. to autoscan for it or add it as a `@Bean`. But tbh my local time is 2pm there are lot of examples at http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`@Configuration`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html) javadoc :

> @Configuration is meta-annotated with @Component, therefore
>   @Configuration classes are candidates for component scanning
>   (typically using Spring XML's  element) and
>   therefore may also take advantage of @Autowired/@Inject at the field
>   and method level **(but not at the constructor level)**.

`@Component`, or `@Service` is more appropriate annotation for services, actually [they are processed differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229282/difference-between-spring-annotations), but in *this* case you have already declared your bean with `@Bean` so you don't  need to use `@Component` and neither any other component scan annotations(@Service, @Repository etc..) because the StatusService bean is already defined via `@Bean` annotated method.

**update** as noted by Sotirios Delimanolis,  Spring process @Bean annotated methods should not contain arguments

```
   @Configuration
   public class CoreConfig {
     @Bean
     public StatusPersistenceService statusPersistenceService(){
     ....
     }

     @Bean
     public StatusService statusService() {
        return new StatusEventHandler(statusPersistenceService());
    }
 }
```

See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html

Comment: This is the correct answer. Note that `@Bean` methods do not accept parameters. OP, you would've seen more errors later on.

Comment: I have statusPersistenceService `@Bean` defined in `PersistenceConfig`. So should the statusService `@Bean` in `CoreConfig` not accept a parameter? Do I `Autowire` statusPersistenceService in that case?

Comment: You can add autowired annotated  field statusPersistenceService to CoreConfig and pass it to the statusService. CoreConfig should be aware of PersistenceConfig to make it possible. You can add PersistenceConfig as classes parameter of Configuration annotation to CoreConfig to achieve this.

Comment: Do you have a link to the reference for this? I can't find it. `@ContextConfiguration(classes = { PersistenceConfig.class })` is that what you mean by adding a classes parameter?

Comment: My bad! Yes I mean `@ContextConfiguratation` of test context framework. If you want to add one `@Configuration` to another you should use `@Import`, sorry for adding confusion. See `Composing @Configuration classes` at http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

Did you give the @Component or @Service annotation in the StatusEventHandler? Please try doing that.