# oauth2 client in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, client

This question is based on the solution in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864295/how-to-use-oauth2resttemplate/49266112#49266112).I implemented the top answer, but I am getting mixed results.

```
String stringObj = restTemplate.getForObject(http://server/rest/api/users?access_token=991949410990808314, String.class);
```

In code I am trying to hit a simple GET endpoint, but I am getting a 401 Unauthorized, but if I copy the rest url + token to my browser it returns the expected json object. Anyone have a clue why?

Answer (score 0):

It is not because you need to put the "Authorization" in the headers and put in you rest call?
Like

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Creds);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem I was having was with

```
@Autowired
RestTemplate restTemplate;
```

The restTemplate was not getting injected as I thought. It worked when I just did:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
```

If anyone has any ideas why @Autowired is not working, I'd love to hear them. Thanks.

Comment: It is because with Spring Boot >= 4 no default bean of RestTemplate is provided. So a bean must be explicity provided. Check this thread below:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28024942/how-to-autowire-resttemplate-using-annotations/42618428#42618428