# Unable to autowire RestTemplate for unit test

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I have a service which uses an autowired instance of `RestTemplate` like below

```
@Service
class SomeAPIService {
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    SomeAPIService(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
        this.restTemplate.setRequestFactory(HttpUtils.getRequestFactory());
    }
}
```

Everything runs fine in non-test environment. But when I try to run following unit test in test profile, it starts complaining about unable to autowire rest template.

```
@RunWith( SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class )
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyApplication.class, webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT, properties = "management.port:0")
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "test")
@EmbeddedPostgresInstance(flywaySchema = "db/migration")
public abstract class BaseTest {
}

@SpringBootTest(classes = SomeAPIService.class)
public class SomeAPIServiceTest extends BaseTest {
    @Autowired
    SomeAPIService someAPIService;

    @Test
    public void querySomeAPI() throws Exception {
        String expected = someAPIService.someMethod("someStringParam");
    }
}
```

Following is the detailed exception -

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'someAPIService': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate'
>   available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

Any clues?

Comment: Have you considered using `@RestClientTest(MyApplication.class)` in conjunction with `@AutoConfigureWebClient(registerRestTemplate = true)`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following helped me get the correct dependencies autowired. The solution is to also include `RestTemplate.class` in list of classes given to `SpringBootTest`.

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {RestTemplate.class, SomeAPIService.class})
class SomeAPIService {
    @Autowired
    SomeAPIService someAPIService;

    @Test
    public void querySomeAPI() throws Exception {
        String expected = someAPIService.someMethod("someStringParam");
    }
}
```

@Emre answer was helpful in guiding me towards the final solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to autowire SomeAPIService without satisfying its dependencies. You should inject Rest Template to SomeAPIService. But you are getting NoSuchBeanDefinitionException for Rest Template.

Take a look how to inject it :

[How to autowire RestTemplate using annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28024942/how-to-autowire-resttemplate-using-annotations)

Comment: I do have a HttpConfiguration class annotated with Configuration with a bean definition for RestTemplate

Comment: Also as i mentioned, I find it hard to understand why everything runs fine in non-test environment while breaks in test enviroment. I have been Autowiring like this without injecting dependencies for other unit tests and never faced a problem.

Comment: Try changing @SpringBootTest(classes = SomeAPIService.class)
 to @SpringBootTest(classes = MyApplication.class)

According to spring boot docs :
"classes
The annotated classes to use for loading an ApplicationContext."

Comment: Thanks Emre. That was helpful and did help me move past the issue but now the active profile has come to haunt. My application requires an additional active profile for certain dependencies to build. I am providing the active profile to maven test like this `mvn test -P myActiveProfile` but its giving me the same error it gives when I drop specifying myActiveProfile in the usual run. wiring issue but of a different kind

Comment: Using `@SpringBootTest(classes = MyApplication.class)` was actually running entire application but not the unit test case

Answer (score 0):

Alternative answer would be - to use `TestRestTemplate`

[From official docs >>>](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-rest-templates-test-utility)

`TestRestTemplate` can be instantiated directly in your integration tests, as shown in the following example:

```java
public class MyTest {

    private TestRestTemplate template = new TestRestTemplate();

    @Test
    public void testRequest() throws Exception {
        HttpHeaders headers = this.template.getForEntity(
                "https://myhost.example.com/example", String.class).getHeaders();
        assertThat(headers.getLocation()).hasHost("other.example.com");
    }

}
```

Alternatively, if you use the `@SpringBootTest` annotation with `WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT` or `WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT`, you can inject a fully configured `TestRestTemplate` and start using it. If necessary, additional customizations can be applied through the `RestTemplateBuilder` bean.