# Spring Boot Error @Autowired RestTemplateBuilder with junit

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

Trying to @Autowired a RestTemplate in Spring Boot 2.1.4 using RestTemplateBuilder.
When i run junit tests i get an error when trying to autowired RestTemplate.

I  saw here: [How to autowire RestTemplate using annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28024942/how-to-autowire-resttemplate-using-annotations)
It seems that RestTemplateBuilder is better so i would like to use that.

This is the configuration file :

```
@Configuration
public class Beans {
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
        return builder.build();
    }
}
```

This is the test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Beans.class)
public class AppTest extends TestCase {
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
}
```

The error is :

```
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method restTemplate in beanDeclerations.Beans required a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder' in your configuration.
```

I edited out other autowired that work.
What am i missing here? 
After searching the web i found out that spring auto wired RestTemplateBuilder, why isn't doing so here?

EDIT:
I ended up using @RestClientTest() and had to move RestTemplateBuilder Bean to the main class for now, I'll move it later to a different place.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-rest-client

Comment: Hi, I think that the RestTemplateBuilder is not configured in your application. You can check https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-template-builder this link to see how to configure RestTemplate using RestTemplateBuilder. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The RestTemplateBuilder should be available through an autocofiguration (see: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/client/RestTemplateAutoConfiguration.java). I think this config is missing because of your @ContextConfiguration. You have some possibilities. Try to add the AutoConfig for the RestTemplateBuilder to your ContextConfiguration. Second one is to make a TestConfiguration and create your own RestTemplateBuilder or directly a RestTemplate. The third one is don't inject the RestTemplate - build it by hand in your test. You can also remove the @ContextConfiguration-Annotation but this will result in a test which loads every config you have defined in your project.

There's also a RestTestTemplate (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testresttemplate) which is designed for tests.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestConfig.class, RestTemplateAutoConfiguration.class})
public class SandboxApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

The snippet above works for me. Without the RestTemplateAutoConfiguration in the ContextConfiguration the RestTemplate can't be created because of the missing RestTemplateBuilder-Bean

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue *(in an Spring Boot 2.5.5 application)*.

To solve it I had to add **@AutoConfigureWebClient** on my test class.

So my test looks like this :

```
@AutoConfigureWebClient
@WebMvcTest(controllers = TeamController.class)
public class TeamControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private FooService fooService;

    @Test
    public void findAllFoos() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/foos"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

But I read somewhere it may be considered as a bug that should be fixed by Spring Team *(maybe will this annotation be directly added in @WebMvcTest ?)*.

I think this way: the test starts and stops faster than when you use @SpringBootTest (because that last one makes your application start entirely).

For more info : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/client/AutoConfigureWebClient.html