# SpringBoot - Testing services

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, junit

I have an SpringBoot app. with this service:

```java
@Slf4j
@Service
public class AddressService {

    private final RegionRepository regionRepository;
    private final CommuneRepository communeRepository;
    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public AddressService(RegionRepository regionRepository,
                          CommuneRepository communeRepository,
                          RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.regionRepository = regionRepository;
        this.communeRepository = communeRepository;
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }

    public GeolocationAddress searchFromAddress(String address) {
        // (..)
    }
}
```

I have created this test:

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
class AddressServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    AddressService addressService;

    @Test
    void searchFromAddress() {
        System.out.println
                (addressService.searchFromAddress("Plaza los Cubos)"));
    }
}
```

But when I run the test I have this error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
```

**Description**:
Parameter 2 of constructor in com.bonansa.service.AddressService required a bean of type 'org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate' that could not be found.

**Action**:
Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate' in your configuration.

Comment: Please show your POM/`build.gradle`. It appears that you don't have the dependency that would auto-configure a `RestTemplate` for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Boot does not automatically configure a RestTemplate. So you cannot autowire a RestTemplate without defining one. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42618428/1992820